# How to deploy a svelte static site in a subfolder?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit to build a very little static website that I deploy manually via SFTP.

When in dev mode, the website is located at the route's root : http://localhost:4173/

But when I deploy it the website is located at : http://example.com/svelte/ and the links and images point to `/` instead of `/svelte`.

I read that I should use the base variable with `npm run build --base=/svelte` but do I have to use it in every `<a href={base}/link>` and `<img src={base}/images/…>` ?

Is there a way to automatically prepend the base option on every links and images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#paths) state regarding links:

> If you find yourself writing this often, it may make sense to extract this into a reusable component.

So yes, just create a component that includes it for you.

For images I would not recommend using paths like that anyway. Instead use `import` in the script to get a URL (for unknown types you might have to configure Vite to [treat the extension as an asset](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#assetsinclude)).

That way the image will be emitted with a hash, so if you change it at any point you will not run into caching problems (the old image being loaded in the browser).

```html
<script>
  import image from '$lib/images/image.jpg';
</script>
<img src={image} ... />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What kind of component would you suggest ? Something like <Link href="" class="" title="" text="" /> ?

Comment: Just like `<a>` but called `Link`. You can use a [`<slot>`](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#slot) for the content and spread [`$$restProps`](https://svelte.dev/docs/basic-markup#attributes-and-props) (only declare `href` explicitly). Markup would be something like: `<a href="{base}{href}" {...$$restProps}><slot /></a>`

Comment: Nice, thanks for your help